# Ambiguity on how service bus/ event hubs charge on AMQP/Https connection

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

Currently we are trying to determine which message service we should use - service bus or event hubs. And then we found that there are ambiguities on the pricing so hope we could get answer here.

**Service bus charge**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/service-bus/

1. in this link above we see that standard tier service bus charges on broker connection. and it measures per hour with the peak of the concurrent connections. So problem is this ,say if I have 5K client, but they don't keep the connection alive, say they they send the message once per minute and only open/close the connection at that time, then the peak of concurrent connections might even lower than 100. In this case, how would connections be calculated. Is it going to be calculated in accumulative way or as the peak of certain time in this hour.
2. in FAQ "*What is a brokered connection and how do I get charged for them?*" mentioned that "*An HTTP call to receive a message from a Service Bus topic or queue that has a receive timeout value greater than zero.*", so what about using HTTP call to send message, how it would be count?
3. And for HTTP call limitation. We could find that there is 5K AMQP connection limit, but what about HTTP? Is it the net messaging refer to? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas .

**Event Hubs charge**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/event-hubs/

In this link above we did not see how it charges on connection, but in FAQ it is saying the charge on connection, free on HTTP while AMQP charge is the same is service bus. So here comes two questions,

1. Is this charge tier matching? Charge on standard tier of event hub on connection is same as standard tier service bus and premium event hubs same as premium service bus? Asking because premium service bus does not charge on connection.

2 For HTTP messaging, same question as in service bus, how many concurrent http connection event hub could support concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

##### Service Bus Charge

1. As the FAQ *What is a brokered connection and how do I get charged for them?* depicts, you will get charged by the hour and prorated for 730 hours in the month.

   If all your clients connect to send messages per minute continuously, the charge would be

   ```
   5000 * 24 * 30.5 / 730 = 5013
   ```

   Since 1K connections are included, you would be charged for the remaining 4013 connections.
2. In this case, this call would just count towards a messaging operation.
3. As mentioned in the docs, REST operations don't count. You could however hit the concurrent receive requests limit.

##### Event Hubs Charge

1. Yes
2. Same as above. No concurrent limit.